# Links aren't clickable, when they're placed over playing YouTube video embed on iPad

Tags: html, ios, iphone, ipad, youtube

I've got menu on tablet resolution with fixed position. Also there is in the content of this page YouTube video embed (iframe).

Now on iPad when you play the YouTube video and than you open a menu item, it shows new element (submenu) which is also position: fixed, but you can't click on any link in this submenu. I've tried to fix it with changing wmode at the begining of url GET parameters like this:

```
wmode=opaque, wmode=transparent
```

But it didn't work. I've also tried to fixed it with changing the YT iframe to object, but it didn't help either.

Basicly if you have any links over playing YouTube video on iPad, you can't click on them. If the video isn't playing, these links work. Is there any solution to fix it, it works well on all desktop browsers.

Comment: Just got same problem! Would like to see a solution!

Comment: Have you solved this?